# To call a method from GUI, which exists in children class

Tags: java, user-interface, methods, jpanel, jlabel

Im trying to call a method from GUI. I have a method in children class which does some calculation. I need to implement that method in GUI and populate the field. My code consist of several classes thats why i didn't post the code but i need to call a method from child class in GUI.

The name of the method is calculateTax(), this is the method I'm trying to access and populate the fields.

```
    public double calculateTaxes()
{
    double tax;
    if ((stateCode.equals("TX")) && getSquareFeet() > 1500)
        tax = getMarketValue()*0.25;
    else if (getSquareFeet() <= 1500 )
        tax = getMarketValue() * 0.10;
    else 
        tax = getMarketValue() * 0.20;
    return tax;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, let's start from basics:
If a method is static, you should be able to call it ChildClass.calculateTax()
otherwise you have to create a class of child instance and then run the method from that instance. Then you can set the value of your GUI field like so:

```
ChildClass child = new ChildClass();
int i = child.calculateTax();
yourFieldInstance.setValue(i);
```

You will get a more accurate response, once you post your actual code and highlight where the problem lies.

Comment: thank you for the response, I've posted my actual method. I just have lot class associated thats why i didn't post the code.